# Detecting custom trackers

Tags: webrtc, speech-recognition

How do I allow certain trackers to be watched when connecting to symbl.ai streaming api? I only want those trackers to be seen when `tracker_response` id detected.

The documentation doesn't give any reference to doing that.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to the symbl.ai team and this was the feedback.
We can utilise ephimeral trackers in streaming APIs. We can also add a trackers array at the global level of the `start_request` we are sending to symbl.ai, and these ephimeral trackers will be utilised in that call.
We can also send the trackerId of any managed tracker you wish to use. We can get the trackerId from the management api GET Trackers api call.
Below is the sample `start_request` you can use for both above cases.

```json
{
    "type": "start_request",
    "insightTypes": [
        "action_item",
        "question"
    ],
    "trackers": [
        {
            "name": "Catch Phrases",
            "vocabulary": [
                "That's the way the news goes",
                "You got it dude",
                "Did I do that",
                "Don't have a cow, man",
                "Yadda yadda yadda",
                "What are your thoughts"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Denial",
            "vocabulary": [
                "No",
                "never agreed to",
                "not interested"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Action",
            "vocabulary": [
                "submit paper",
                "please leave a message after a tone"
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "123456789" //ID can be taken from management api
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "confidenceThreshold": 0.5,
        "timezoneOffset": 480,
        "languageCode": "en-US",
        "speechRecognition": {
            "sampleRateHertz": 16000
        },
        "trackers": {
            "interimResults": true
        }
    }
}
```

Also note this down.
Make sure that the websocket instance that publishes audio stream, adds the custom to trackers incase you having another websocket instance that is joining the conversation is listen-only mode.